# ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Failed to activate the given service account. Please ensure provided key file is valid

Tags: authentication, gcloud, google-speech-api

I'm trying to follow this guide https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started to call GAE speech to text api through curl. But it doesn't seem to work.

I've setup a project and enabled speech to text api. But then when I try to active the service account it fails. I've run diagnostics, tried different accounts, verified the json file (has email), tried gcloud beta init :-(

bash-3.2$ gcloud auth activate-service-account account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=project.json
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Failed to activate the given service account. Please ensure provided key file is valid.

The next step though 'gcloud auth print-access-token' returns a token.

But the final step (curl) returns this -

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google Cloud Speech API has not been used in project google.com:cloudsdktool before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

The problem seems to lie in the project(google.com:cloudsdktool instead of mine) used to authenticate the incoming request.

I'm guessing the call to activate-service-account is causing this?

Comment: File a bug here? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error message for `google.com:cloudsdktool` project because the command you ran with curl `gcloud auth print-access-token` was using your user account credentials (created by `gcloud auth login`) and not service account (as you point out that step failed for you).

The [command to activate service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) is correct (btw you do not need to provide the account, as one from the file will be used)

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=project.json
```

Make sure your `project.json` is correct file in the right format format. You can create this json key file either in

1. in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
2. `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create`, see [reference guide](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create).

The file will look like

```
{
  "private_key_id": "....",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "...",
  "client_id": "...",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

Note that `client_email` will be used for ACCOUNT in `activate-service-account` command.